# FILES REST API url to list specific folder content

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, rest

I need to retrieve the items/documents in a specific folder of our Office 365 hosted SharePoint site, but I always get an resource error. I'm trying to use the FILE REST API for this, documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/files-rest-operations

The url to the SharePoint site with the files is https://informationresourcemanager.sharepoint.com/irm/fido/1074/Forms/AllItems.aspx

and according to the MSDN documents the call should be

```
GET {base-url}/Files/{folder-id}/children
```

and "base-url" should in the case of SharePoint be

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/{site-path}/_api/v1.0
```

Now, I've tried 10 different combinations without getting any good results, so I guess I'm doing something wrong with the base-url or the site-path. Is the correct base-url this for my site

```
https://informationresourcemanager.sharepoint.com/irm/fido/_api/v1.0/
```

or just

```
https://informationresourcemanager.sharepoint.com/irm/_api/v1.0/
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend You to use GraphApi, better and MS recommends to use it too:

[MS Docs GraphApi](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)

and use it like this:

**Library Folders**
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<id>/lists/<LibraryName>/drive/root/children/<FolderPath>/children` 
to get the folder contents. Find article [here.](https://concurrency.com/blog/november-2018/using-the-graph-api-with-sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

Use the one ending `fido` and add `/_api/v1.0/files/root` to the end.

This will give you the folders in the web. Including the url for your document library as a rest URL.

If you used the one ending in `irm` it would cause the rest api to run against that web rather than the `fido` web.

Comment: If I try just the URL https://informationresourcemanager.sharepoint.com/irm/fido/_api/v1.0/ I get this json back: {"@odata.context":"https://informationresourcemanager.sharepoint.com/irm/fido/_api/v1.0/$metadata","value":[{"name":"files","kind":"EntitySet","url":"files"},{"name":"drive","kind":"Singleton","url":"drive"},{"name":"me","kind":"Singleton","url":"me"}]}

Comment: Adding /files/root to the end of that url above gives me a 404 :(

Comment: So you see that there is a reference to files in the JSON response you posted. you can just add files/root. That will give you the content in that web. I have tried this on my 365 tenant

Comment: Thanks, I will have to try this tomorrow again in detail.